# Storing a URL from a basic page using a custom module

Tags: 7, hooks

I created a basic page at http://example.com/[company]/[customer]?id=2. I want to store this URL in a global variable for string manipulations within a custom module.

I succeeded to retrieve the URL by using `hook_form_alter()` with respect to a **webform** but I don't know how to do the same thing for a **basic page**.

Which hook do I need to use?

Comment: I take company/customer is a path alias for the node being saved, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. It is the path alias.

Comment: If you have the nid, you could query the url_alias table to get the path.

Comment: @No Sssweat I want to retrieve the whole url so that I can extract the parameter "**2**" with string manipulation.

Comment: ok, you could use  `$url = current_path(); // gets the current page url.` then string manipulate to get parameter 2.

Comment: @No Sssweat Understood but which hook shall I use? For forms, you can use hook_form_alter. What can I use for pages?

Comment: Here is a list of [all the hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7.x) so use hook_node_view() if you want this to happen when the node is viewed. else use some other hook_node_SOMETHING(). The description tells you when the hook is triggered

Comment: As @NoSssweat says, you need to choose your own hook. As for getting the path and the query params you can use [`request_uri`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7.x). `current_path` will return you node/ID instead of company/customer you'll have to request the company/customer url through `drupal_get_path_alias` and then append the querystring variables using `drupal_get_query_parameters` and `drupal_http_build_query`.

Comment: @Beebee `current_path will return you node/ID` interesting, I guess when I used it, it worked since my url path was from a view. To get the node alias apprently you can do it like this `$path = current_path();
$path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);`

Comment: @NoSssweat yeah, current_path, request_path, request_uri all work slightly differently and should be used in different contexts. See the first comment on this [`request_uri`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7.x#comment-40018) documentation page for `example.com/drupal/documentation?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module, try to implement the **hook_preprocess_page**

```
function my_module_preprocess_page($vars) {
  print_r(current_path());exit;
}
```

This will retrieve the current URL of the site.

Comment: Can **$vars** be replaced by **$node**?

Comment: No. Just print the $vars you can able to see your node properties.

Comment: if you need $node use `$node = menu_get_object();` don't forget to check if it's actually a node and not `NULL`!

Comment: @Beebee I used "**$node=menu_get_object();**" and used this line of code "**$nid=$node->nid**". This works but as soon as I restart the experiment, it stays on the first id and don't change. When I clean my cache, I get this error notice: "**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in lettable_process_page_alter()**". How can I solve this issue?